# bitwise operation to compare values

Tags: java, bitwise-operators

I have four type of sectors each represents by a binary byte:

```
sector one:   0000 0001
sector two:   0000 0010
sector three: 0000 0100
sector four:  0000 1000
```

Now, I got a function which returns a integer value, I need to check whether this value is one of the sectors. What is the most efficient way to check it? I mean a bitwise operation.

```
int val = func();
//check if val is one of the sector
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
boolean isSectorOne (int val) {return (val & 0x01) == 0x01;}
boolean isSectorTwo (int val) {return (val & 0x02) == 0x02;}    
boolean isSectorThree (int val) {return (val & 0x04) == 0x04;}
boolean isSectorFour (int val) {return (val & 0x08) == 0x08;}
```